# Visual Studio with CMake stopped working. How do I completely reset to a working state?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, ninja

I was working on a C++ CMake project which was displaying and building fine in Visual Studio. Then I did something, I'm not sure what I did, but it seemed to break CMake. Now I get the following error:

```
Error       CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: E:/DOCS/PROGRAMMING/22-02_Qt/vs_simple/VsConsole5/out/build/x64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_c94d5 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_c94d5.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_c94d5.exe
    FAILED: cmTC_c94d5.exe 
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_c94d5.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1434~1.319\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_c94d5.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_c94d5.exe /implib:cmTC_c94d5.lib /pdb:cmTC_c94d5.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1434~1.319\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_c94d5.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj /out:cmTC_c94d5.exe /implib:cmTC_c94d5.lib /pdb:cmTC_c94d5.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_c94d5.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_c94d5.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.        C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake    69
```

I get this error, even if I make a completely fresh CMake project via `File` > `New` > `Project` > `CMake Project` from within Visual Studio.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing:

- Visual Studio
- Multiple different Windows SDK versions
- CMake

I was hoping that doing this would return Visual Studio + CMake to a working state again but I am still getting the same error.

I also tried manually setting `LIB` and `INCLUDE` environment variables to the appropriate directories and that did get rid of the error but then the program wouldn't build, I got a bunch of errors like this:

`Error (active) E1696   cannot open source file "ctype.h"   VsSimple.exe - x64-Debug    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\cctype`

I also tried deleting everything in the project folder apart from `CMakeLists.txt`, the `.cpp` file and the `.h` file. Unfortunately still no luck.

Comment: Maybe your sdk path has changed because of a Visual Studio update. If this happens when using CMake-GUI I just force a regeneration and all is well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, how do I force a regeneration?

Comment: In CMake-GUI press the configure button then generate.

Comment: Yes, the `cctype` file exists in the directory specified.

CMake-GUI is able to make a Visual Studio solution that works fine if I choose `Visual Studio 17 2022` as the generator but this is not ideal because I would like to work with the cmake project directly. When I select Ninja, I get an error:

```CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.```

Comment: Just delete cmake cache and run configure again. You may also need to remove `.vs` folder near your root `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: I tried deleting everything in the project folder apart from `CMakeLists.txt`, the `.cpp` file and the `.h` file. Unfortunately still no luck. (I'll add this info to the main question for clarity).

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this for a few hours, I found that by changing the **Cmake generator**, under CMakeSettings.json in VisualStudio, **from Ninja to Visual Studio 17 2022 Win64** it is able to compile the test program successfully, and everything works.